# How to remove US dictionaries from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04

The Ubuntu 22.04 snap installation of Firefox appears to include the US language pack and dictionary which cannot be removed.  From the Firefox settings and add-ons menus I have installed English GB and French dictionaries and have removed the US ones but the US dictionary menu option, (in spelling), keeps showing up and the dictionary is still there.

[Firefox right click spell menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kK54.png)

Research on the Mozilla site reveals that 1. this is appears to be a bug and 2. you could manually delete the dictionary by going to /usr/share/hunspell and deleting en_US.dic and associated en_US.aff.  I say "could" because I believe this is for non snap installations. I deleted these files it and it made no difference for me.

These dictionary files are also in various /snap read-only sub-directories which I could not delete, even as root.

In any event, I spent some hours trying to figure out how to get rid of an annoying, unwanted American dictionary and eventually gave up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 steps in Firefox to have FF check against the English (UK) dictionary. I've just done this in a new instance of FF on v22.04 (APT version - I removed the snap) but it should work just the same (indeed it does having checked on a 22.04 PC with the snap version of FF).

1. Install English (GB) **Language Pack** (add on)
2. Install British English **Dictionary** (Marco Pinto) (add on)
3. Hamburger menu → Settings → Language  → select the
   drop down menu against the currently selected language and select
   **English (GB).**

[image]

Without installing Marco Pinto dictionary (step 2) but with English (GB) language selected, spelling will continue to be checked against English (US) spellings so this step is key.

Voila!

EDIT: checked again in 22.04 and it seems that by following these steps, whilst the the US language is replaced by the GB one as the selected language it is no longer a factor although still a selectable option if required. In the `Set Alternatives...` box next to the chosen default, it mentions that FF will display the first one listed as your default and will display alternatives in the order they appear but whilst you may delete any **after** the first two, you cannot delete the second one as the `Remove` option is greyed out on selection. ) See graphic above). The option remains to reorder the list by moving an option `Up or Down`.

I'm not sure that this is actually a bug in FF but simply a logic issue. You cannot have `Alternatives` if you have only one one available.

Comment: ...and which of those steps removes the US dictionaty?

Comment: Checked again in 22.04 and it seems that by following these steps, the US dictionary is replaced by the GB one as default so is no longer a factor. Thanks for the reminder. I've added the additional information to my answer.

Comment: I have done all this but the US spelling menu option persists. 

"I'm not sure that this is actually a bug in FF but simply a logic issue. You cannot have Alternatives if you have only one one available."

The only language you cannot delete is US, which always remains greyed out no matter how many alternatives there are.  In any event, I think this is a red herring as this settings pertains to : "the languages used to display menus, messages, and notifications from Firefox", and not the spell check.

Whether you class this as a bug or not it is certainly a massive GUI imperfection.

Comment: odd, since I took all those steps yesterday in FF (also previously in 20.04) and whilst my test word "color" was not underlined by the spell checker but "colour" was before I did it, afterwards the correct result was obtained. Did you close FF and reopen it? Aslo, which language have you got selected in `settings` under Ubuntu?